# Flutter syntax highlighting not working after new UI In Android Studio Giraffe update

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio, syntax-highlighting

I updated my Android Studio to Android Studio Giraffe with new UI then my all Flutter projects' syntax highlighting and context menu suggestions stopped working.

[image]

I tried the following steps.

1. Restart Android Studio
2. Re-associate the file with Dart type (go to the menu bar >> File >> File Properties >> Associate with File Type...)
3. Restart my laptop

But none of this helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after searching a lot of web pages, I got the solution as follows.

1. Go to Plugins
2. Uninstall Flutter then Dart Plugin (remember, uninstall, not disable)
3. Restart Android Studio
4. Install Dart then Flutter Plugin again
5. Restart Android Studio

And all is done and back again.

Comment: It is not working... I did many times... :(

Comment: What's the error you are experiencing...???

Comment: Now, it is fixed. Just remove all flutter-related plugins and reinstall them one by one many of them might not work.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a rare occurrence, but changing the Kotlin Compiler version to bundled fixed it for me. I was getting an error `Failed to download Kotlin Compiler Maven artifact` and the syntax highlight wasn't working. Changing Kotlin Compiler to bundled version fixed the highlight.